# Is the converse of this true?

Tags: differential-geometry

I was reading this [reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffeomorphism#Homeomorphism_and_diffeomorphism) and I was wondering if someone can provide a proof of the converse, well if it is true of course, I mean if two smooth manifolds are diffeomorphic then they have to be homeomorphic, and if fact does the inverse of a diffeomorphism has to be a diffeomorphism ?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: You are asking if two manifolds are diffeomorphic implies they are homeomorphic?

Comment: Yes, and if you have a diffeormorphism then the inverse should be one as well :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are true. If manifolds $M$ and $N$ are diffeomorphic, there exists a differentiable bijection $f:M\to N$ which has a differentiable inverse (a diffeomorphism). Since differentiability implies continuity, $f$ is a continuous bijection with a continuous inverse, a homeomorphism. Thus, $M$ and $N$ are homeomorphic.

If $f$ is a diffeomorphism, it is a differentiable bijection with a differentiable inverse. The inverse of a bijection is always a bijection, and $(f^{-1})^{-1}=f$, so $(f^{-1})^{-1}$ is also differentiable. Thus, $f^{-1}$ is a diffeomorphism.

**Edit:**

If your definition of diffeomorphism is $f:M\to N$ is a diffeomorphism if it is a continuous bijection such that $X\subset M$ is a chart if and only if $f(X)$ is a chart in $N$, then both are still true. To get that $f$ is a homeomorphism, we need to show that $f^{-1}$ is continuous. Let $U\subset M$ be open. Then $U$ can be written as a union of charts, $U=\bigcup U_\alpha$. Thus, $f(U_\alpha)=V_\alpha$ is a chart in $N$. We see that $$f(U)=f\left(\bigcup_\alpha U_\alpha\right)=\bigcup_\alpha f(U_\alpha)=\bigcup_\alpha V_\alpha.$$
Thus, $f(U)$ is open in $N$, so $f^{-1}$ is continuous, and $f$ is a homeomorphism.

To show that $f^{-1}$ is a diffeomorphism, we have to show that it is continuous (done), a bijection (done), and $X$ is a chart in $N$ if and only if $f^{-1}(X)$ is a chart in $M$. Let $X$ be a chart in $N$. Let $Y=f^{-1}(X)$. Then $f(Y)=X$ is a chart in $N$, so by assumption $Y$ is a chart in $M$. Now let $X$ be any set in $N$ such that $f^{-1}(X)=Y$ is a chart in $M$. Then $f(Y)=X$ is a chart in $N$.

Comment: Don't we have to use charts ?

Comment: It's not necessary, as I just showed.

Comment: Ok :) I thought that a diffeomorphism between manifolds if there is a 1-1 continuous map $f$ such that if $X$ is a chart in $M$ iff $f \circ X$ is a chart in $N$ :)

Comment: Interesting. I have never heard such a definition. A more common definition is the one I gave, a differentiable bijection with a differentiable inverse.

Comment: And what about the result with my definition?

Comment: The first holds for sure because of the invariance of domain theorem. The second is also true because of the "if and only if" in the definition. Let me know if you want some more detail.

Comment: Can you detail more this in your above answer please?

Comment: Done. See my recent edit.

Comment: Ok just a second :)

Comment: Thanks :), do you know something about Fourier analysis?